# How to remove a file moved with a FileUpLoad [asp.net] C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, stream, move

I have a process that loads, process and MOVES a file CSV. This behavior has been represented by 2 ways, but I have a problem in the 2nd one described below:

1. The source and destination directories are set in a database. So read and move the file works excellent disappearing the copy from the source directory. (GOOD)
2. The source directory has been got from a FileUpload control (fuControl.PostedFile.FileName) and destination is still set in a database. So read and move the file, but at this point, I see that the file is copied into destination directory but a locked copy remains in the source directory and only disappears if I refresh the page (F5) or quit the internet browser. (NOT GOOD) So, How can I avoid this?

Here my sample code:

```
    private void RunProcess(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                this.ProcessFile(stream);
            }
            string destination = this.GetDestinationPath(); //Get the path from DB
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            File.Move(path, destination + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

**-----EDIT-----**

I have my FileUpload control in a repeater and I use it like this. It's not working, a copy is still remaining.

```
    protected void repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Browse")
        {
            using (FileUpload fuSource = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fuSource"))
            {
                if (fuSource != null)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fuSource.FileName) == false)
                    {
                        string filePath = fuSource.PostedFile.FileName;
                        this.RunProcess(filePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

**-----EDIT 2-----**

```
    public void ProcessFile(StreamReader stream)
    {
        string line = String.Empty;
        while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Just 1 line.
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is disposeable and as such it should be wrapped in a using statement.  This should release any file locks that would otherwise be held until the web application times out.

```
using(var fileUploadControl = new FileUpload())//...
```

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey -  Thanks for your answer. I edited my question showing how I use my fileupload (Edit section) It's not working.

Comment: Its possible something is long executing, `RunProcess`?  Debug it by writing something out to a label control just after the using statement block ends. This way you know you exited the using statement block and therefore disposal occurred.

Comment: Actually the process of very simple. I've already verified debugging and everything's done. RunProcess is exposed above my edit section and inside there is a ProcessFile which open the file and read just 1 line. Then continues with the move.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus - Please show the code for `RunProcess`.  Because that process is tinkering with the file I/O it could just as easily be causing a file lock and require release of resources.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey posted as Edit2

Comment: There still appears to be code missing.  Best I can tell I see that the stream is not being disposed of.  Needs a using statement.  On iPhone now hard to read.